# Optimal Algorithm to find Anagrams of a string in another string

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I came across this topic in Cracking The Coding Interview book. The challenge is to find permutations of a given smaller string s in bigger string b. I could come up with the below algorithm whose Time Complexity is O(B x S) where S and B are lengths of given smaller and bigger Strings respectively:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class AnagramAlgorithm {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "cbabadcbbabbcbabaabccbabc";
    String b = "abbc";

    printAnagramsOfB(s, b);
}

public static void printAnagramsOfB(String text, String pattern) {
    if(isEmpty(text) || isEmpty(pattern)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Strings");
        return;
    }
    int patternLength = pattern.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - patternLength + 1; i++) {
        String substring = text.substring(i, i + patternLength);
        if (isAnagram(pattern, substring)) {
            System.out.println("Anagram Found : " + substring);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
    return str == null || str.length() == 0;
}

public static boolean isAnagram(String pattern, String substring) {
    if (pattern.length() != substring.length()) {
        System.out.println("SubString length doesn't match the length of Given String");
        return false;
    }
    char[] subStringArr = substring.toCharArray();
    char[] patternArr = pattern.toCharArray();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> mapPattern = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> mapSubstring = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < subStringArr.length; i++) {
        if (mapSubstring.containsKey(subStringArr[i])) {
            int count = mapSubstring.get(subStringArr[i]);
            mapSubstring.put(subStringArr[i], count + 1);
        } else {
            mapSubstring.put(subStringArr[i], 1);
        }
        if (mapPattern.containsKey(patternArr[i])) {
            int count = mapPattern.get(patternArr[i]);
            mapPattern.put(patternArr[i], count + 1);
        } else {
            mapPattern.put(patternArr[i], 1);
        }
    }
    return mapPattern.equals(mapSubstring);
}
}
```

In the book it's mentioned that the most optimal algorithm is of O(B). I couldn't come up with such algorithm. As per my thoughts, for the overall complexity to be O(B), the algorithm to find whether the substring is an anagram should be O(1) i.e., without any loops. Is that even possible? Or is there any other way to implement the most optimal algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm runs in linear time. If you are preparing for an interview, then you can probably find out what is going on here by yourself ;)

```java
public class Solver {

    List<Integer> solve(String t, String s) {

        HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountInT = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
            Character c = t.charAt(i);
            if (charCountInT.containsKey(c)) {
                charCountInT.put(c, charCountInT.get(c) + 1);
            }
            else {
                charCountInT.put(c, 1);
            }
        }

        HashMap<Character, Integer> extraCharacters = new HashMap<>();
        for (Character c : charCountInT.keySet()) {
            extraCharacters.put(c, -charCountInT.get(c));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
            Character c = s.charAt(i);
            if (extraCharacters.containsKey(c)) {
                extraCharacters.put(c, extraCharacters.get(c) + 1);
            }
        }

        int expectedZeroesInExtraCharacters = charCountInT.size();
        int zeroesInExtraCharacters = 0;
        for (Integer count : extraCharacters.values()) {
            if (count == 0) ++zeroesInExtraCharacters;
        }

        List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();
        if (zeroesInExtraCharacters == expectedZeroesInExtraCharacters) answer.add(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < s.length() - t.length(); i++) {

            Character nextChar = s.charAt(t.length() + i - 1);
            if (charCountInT.containsKey(nextChar)) {
                extraCharacters.put(nextChar, extraCharacters.get(nextChar) + 1);
                if (extraCharacters.get(nextChar) == 0) ++zeroesInExtraCharacters;
                if (extraCharacters.get(nextChar) == 1) --zeroesInExtraCharacters;
            }

            Character removedChar = s.charAt(i - 1);
            if (charCountInT.containsKey(removedChar)) {
                extraCharacters.put(removedChar, extraCharacters.get(removedChar) - 1);
                if (extraCharacters.get(removedChar) == 0) ++zeroesInExtraCharacters;
                if (extraCharacters.get(removedChar) == -1) --zeroesInExtraCharacters;
            }

            if (zeroesInExtraCharacters == expectedZeroesInExtraCharacters) answer.add(i);
        }

        return answer;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String t = "abbc";
        String s = "cbabadcbbabbcbabaabccbabc";
        List<Integer> startIndices = new Solver().solve(t, s);
        System.out.println(startIndices);
        for (int startIndex : startIndices) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(startIndex, startIndex + t.length()));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why do we have to loop through the bigger string in 2 parts? 0 to t.length() and then t.length() to s.length() - t.length()..

Comment: @NeerajaGandla The first one builds a frequency map for the string `t`, the second one builds frequency maps of each substring of `s` of length `t.length()`, to compare with the precomputed frequency map of `t`. The trick that makes it O(B) instead of O(BS) is that the frequency map can be updated from one substring to the next in O(1) time.

Comment: The other thing that's needed for the algorithm to be linear is that comparing two frequency maps takes O(1) time, assuming the strings are formed from a fixed alphabet.

Comment: @kaya3 Assuming that HashMap get and put operations run in O(1), my algorithm runs in linear time even for not-fixed alphabet, because it doesn't compare frequency maps.

Comment: @ardenit Oh, good point, I didn't read carefully enough. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

The standard anagram finding method uses a sorted version to compare.  You do not look for "TARGET", you put it into alphabetical order first: "AEGRTT" and search for that.

Take the relevant number of characters, six for "AEGRTT", from the start of the bigger string.  Sort and compare to see if you have a match.  Then drop the first letter and add the next letter from the long list in the appropriate position -- the list is already sorted which will help.  Compare again and repeat.

Comment: Better to use a frequency map than a sorted array; updating the sorted array of length S still takes O(S) time, as will comparing two sorted arrays, so the algorithm will end up being O(BS) overall.